# What is the reason behind var a = (expression1, expression2) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Looking through some JS code I have found something like this:

```
var a, b;
if (  
  (a = someFunction1(), b = someFunction2() )
){
   ...
}
```

I never found anything like this previously and I do not understand the reason for doing something like this. Therefore I am curious: is the person who has done this out of his mind or am I just not capable to understand his idea.

When I try to check what construct like `(expression1, expression2)` does, I see that it always returns the value of the second expression:

```
(5, 6)   // 6
('strange', 'things')    // 'things'
(4, undefined)     // undefined
```

So if I would be the one writing this code, I would do something like this:

```
var a = someFunction1(),
    b = someFunction2();

if (b){ ... }
```

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Comment: Was that minified code?

Comment: @Bergi doesn't seem like it, since there's excessive whitespace everywhere in this code.

Comment: Consider what happens if someFunction1 causes side-effects, especially if someFunction2 is affected by said side-effects.  Personally, I wouldn't write code this way, but some people apparently do.

Comment: @Joeytje50: That might just be auto-indentation (either for posting here, or by the devtools displaying the code, or…)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There still would be no difference? This is javascript, the order of evaluations is closely specified.

Comment: @Bergi Sadly it is not minified code.

Comment: @Bergi: The fact that the two functions are in the same `if` condition suggests that they are somehow tied together conceptually in some way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, they might. I just thought your comment would indicate that the order of evaluation might be unspecified, therefore you did consider this unreliable. Nvm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I try to check what construct like `(expression1, expression2)` does, I see that it always returns the value of the second expression

Yes. Even without trying out, this is what the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) does.

> Am I correct in my reasoning?

Yes. Your code does exactly the same thing, but is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, that is essentially `if(b)`. The readability of the first version is terrible and does not save on space so it would make no sense for it to be minified like that.

Assigning variables inside of conditional statements is bad practice.